# fetch and remove innerHTML from JSON using the same button

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have an external JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "label": "2017-03-30",
    "value": "1675000",
    "accessories": "true"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "label": "2017-04-01",
    "value": "1440000",
    "accessories": "true"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "label": "2017-04-02",
    "value": "830000",
    "accessories": "false"
  }
]
```

I can fetch the JSON using the following button and it displays in the div ID of accessories:

```
<button id="button2">Get Customers</button>

<h1>Brands that sell Accessories:</h1>
    <div id="accessories"></div>
```

The JavaScript I am using is:

```
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener
('click', loadData);

function loadData(e) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status === 200) {
      // console.log(this.responseText);

      const customers = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      let output = '';

      customers.forEach(function(customer) {
       output += `
        <ul>
          <li>Company ID: ${customer.id}</li>
          <li>Company label: ${customer.label}</li>
          <li>Company value: ${customer.value}</li>
          <li>Company Accessories: ${customer.accessories}</li>
        </ul>
        `;
      })
        document.getElementById('accessories').innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
};
```

This outputs the company information in bullet points.
What I want to do next is remove the HTML by pressing the same button but I'm struggling to keep it removed.

I've tried:

```
function removeAcc() {
  document.getElementById('accessories').innerHTML = '';
}
```

But it just flashes back to the same list.
Help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the current state of your program somewhere so that you know if the "external JSON" was already loaded or not. This way you can switch the action in the eventListener like so:

```js
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', toggleData);

function toggleData(e) {
  if(hasData) {
    removeAcc()
    hasData = false;
  } else {
    loadData(e)
    hasData = true;
  }
 }
```